# Порядок слов в словосочетании запроса губит выдачу в Sphinx

Tags: php, sphinx

Использую для поиска по каталогу Shpinx. Столкнулся с тем, что он строг к последовательности слов в запросе. Можно ли раздробить запрос на отдельные слова и объединить выдачу?

Пример запроса и количество найденных страниц:

икра черная* — 0 найдено
черная икра* — 7 найдено
икра* — 62 найдено
черная* — 23 найдено

Привожу запрос к виду: *икра* | *черная*, происходит выдача, где выводится 1 результат, вот он "ИКРА ПАЛТУСА ЧЕРНАЯ РОССИЯ ..". Казалось бы, слова есть, но они в том порядке, что и по запросу, сначала "икра" потом "черная". Он не находит "черная икра".

Как можно разбить запрос на несколько мелких и объединить их?

Про expand_keywords = 1 знаю, не помогает

Comment: 1. Конфиг `index` в студию 2. Чем выбираете - через SQL образный запрос или устаревшее API?

Comment: Проблема решена простой переиндексацией